# If I edit my post and a member edits that, does it show up as them having the final edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently posted a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826348/exposing-powershell-type-definition-from-module).

I made an edit because I realised that the code block was wrong.

I then saw there was an edit by someone else that doesn't look that much different. Is this simply an edit on my edit that was moderated by a user or is this their own edit on top of mine?

Answer (score 7):

Your edit was done during the 5 minutes grace period, hence not showing in the revisions at all. We can't know how the question looked like before your edit.

While you were editing, the other user clicked "edit" too and started editing as well. You submitted your edit first, and as I said above, since it was in the grace period, it overwrote the original question.

After you edited, the other user, who has full edit privileges, submitted their own edit. It was probably almost the same edit as you made, hence the weird revision which doesn't really show any change.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44826348/revisions) to see what the edit changed, and whether it ended up reverting your changes or not.

Since you were making an edit, and not *suggesting* an edit, the edit was simply another user editing the post after you edited it, not them affecting the edit that you made.

Comment: So, their edit would have been a suggested edit and had to be vetted by other SO users?

Comment: No, it was not.  They have the privilege (as do you) to edit posts without review.  If, however, you try to edit my post here (where you don't have 2k rep) you will be *suggesting* an edit, rather than unilaterally making one.

Comment: Ok, so this change is purely aesthetical.

Comment: Not really, revision history does not show edits made during grace period, which appears to be the source of confusion here.